# Finding pairs of commuting rationals

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm trying to solve the following problem. Consider $X = \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\}$ and the binary operation $a \star b = \frac{a}{b}$. Given this operation, I'm trying to find all pairs of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ that commute.

My attempt is as follows. Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\}$ and write $a = \frac{m}{n}, b = \frac{p}{q}$, so $m,n,p,q \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$. We have
\begin{align*}
a \star b = b \star a & \iff \frac{a}{b} = \frac{b}{a} \\
& \iff \frac{\frac{m}{n}}{\frac{p}{q}} = \frac{\frac{p}{q}}{\frac{m}{n}} \\
& \iff \frac{m}{n} \cdot \frac{q}{p} = \frac{p}{q} \cdot\frac{n}{m} \\
& \iff \frac{mq}{pn} = \frac{pn}{mq} \\
& \iff (mq)^2 = mqmq = (pn)^2 = pnpn \\
& \iff mq = \pm pn. 
\end{align*}
I can't figure out how to proceed from where. I don't think this is a fully simplified condition, but I can't cross-multiply with non-integers in the numerator/denominator, so I have to introduce integer quotients.

Comment: Isn't it simpler just to note that $a \star b = b \star a \iff a^2=b^2 \iff a= \pm b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think you can't cross multiply non-integers? If $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{b}{a}$ then $a^2 = b^2$. If you like, this can be simplified further to $a = \pm b$.

This is exactly what you got at the end of your computation as well, since if $a = \frac{m}{n}$ and $b = \frac{p}{q}$, the condition $mq = \pm pn$ is the same thing as $\frac{m}{n} = \pm \frac{p}{q}$ by dividing both sides by $qn$.

You can also check this by graphing. Desmos will happily plot the solutions to $\frac{x}{y} = \frac{y}{x}$, and you can see the solution is exactly $x = \pm y$.

[image: a desmos graph of x/y = y/x]

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $a \star b = b \star a$ iff $|a|=|b|$. Equivalently, $a \star b = b \star a$ iff $a \in \{-b,b\}$.

Indeed, the simplest way I know to see this avoids algebra. Instead, just note the following: if on the one hand $|a|>|b|$ [by the usual ordering] then $|a \star b| > 1$ while $|b \star a| < 1$, so then $a \star b$ cannot equal $b \star a$. And then on the other hand it is easy to check that $a \star a = 1$ and $a \star -a = -a \star a = -1$.